# Collision detection for sprites in the current room

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I asked a similar question not long ago regarding collision detection on rocks. I have multiple rooms with a group of rocks in each. The collision detection for these rocks is in the player class. My question here is how do I set it so that the collision detection works for the rocks in these rooms?

When i run the script and try to move my character it gives this error:

```
line 34, in move_single_axis
    for rock in current_room.rock_list:
NameError: name 'current_room' is not defined
```

Here is the code which is broken up into multiple files.

## PLAYER CLASS FILE

```
import pygame


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, filename, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        if x != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(x, 0)
        if y != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(0, y)

    def move_single_axis(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x += x
        self.rect.y += y

        for rock in current_room.rock_list:

            if self.rect.colliderect(rock.rect):
                if x > 0:
                    self.rect.right = rock.rect.left
                if x < 0:
                    self.rect.left = rock.rect.right
                if y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = rock.rect.top
                if y < 0:
                    self.rect.top = rock.rect.bottom
```

## ROOMS CLASS FILE

```
import Player
import pygame
from Rock import *


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


class Room(object):
    rock_list = None

    def __init__(self):

        self.rock_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


class Room0(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        rock = Rock("Rock.png", 200, 200)
        self.rock_list.add(rock)

        self.background_position = [0, 0]
        self.background_image = pygame.image.load("Floor.png").convert()
```

## ROCK CLASS FILE

```
import pygame


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)



class Rock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, filename, x, y):

        super().__init__()    

        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().inflate(1, 1)
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
```

## MAIN LOOP FILE

```
import Rock
from Rooms import *
from Player import *
import pygame


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


pygame.init()

screen_width = 1080
screen_height = 607
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

pygame.display.set_caption('Labyrinth')

block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
rock_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player("Isaac.png", 420, 150)
all_sprites_list.add(player)

rooms = []

room = Room0()
rooms.append(room)

current_room_no = 0
current_room = rooms[current_room_no]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


done = False


# -- MAIN PROGRAM LOOP -- #

# -- Event processing --

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

# Player controls

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[ord('a')]:
        player.changespeed(-7, 0)
    if key[ord('d')]:
        player.changespeed(7, 0)
    if key[ord('w')]:
        player.changespeed(0, -7)
    if key[ord('s')]:
        player.changespeed(0, 7)

# -- Game Logic --

    all_sprites_list.update()

# Hit detection 

    blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)

    screen.blit(current_room.background_image, current_room.background_position)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    current_room.rock_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you're trying to use a global `current_room` variable in your `Player` class, but it doesn't exist in this module, it only exists in the MAIN LOOP FILE. I think the easiest solution would be to pass the room to the player and to add it as an attribute:

```
# In the main loop file.
# Pass the current_room to the Player's __init__ method.
player = Player("Isaac.png", 420, 150, current_room)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, filename, x, y, current_room):
        super().__init__()
        # Add the room as an attribute.
        self.current_room = current_room
        # ...

    def move_single_axis(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x += x
        self.rect.y += y
        # Use the `self.current_room` attribute.
        for rock in self.current_room.rock_list:
            # ...
```

When the room gets changed, you also have to change the `player.current_room` attribute.

Comment: Oh thanks that worked brilliantly! thankyou for helping me understand what had to be done!!

Answer (score 1):

You could always just pass the current_room as a parameter to a set function in the player class so the player stores a reference of the current room.

1. Create a new var for the player.
2. Create a set function and pass in the current room.
3. Use that reference in your player move_single_axis function.

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand how to do what you recommended, is it possible to give a bit more detail on what to do?

Comment: Create a set function in your player class and local variable called current_room. Pass in the global variable current_room with the function, set_room(current_room), so the player class has a reference to the room it's in. you're getting the error, because current_room can't be detected from within the player class, so that's why you need to pass it to the player. For instance, every time you switch rooms you call set_room for the player to get the correct room.